# Pandas, Covent column into header and multiply by another column

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

This problem is about converting column into header and multiplying values in pandas

[image: My input look like this]

I need to convert low_value values to become header and multiply values

[image: Into something like that (not necessary need to store values as headers but just need to multiply like showed]

I would appreciate any suggestion as I am beginner. I am able to

```
for i in df3['Total']:
    for j in df3['low_value']:
        print(i*j)
```

but don't know how to store it in df.

Comment: Don't post data is images, post as text.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

1. I read one column as list

`list_of_values = df3.low_value.to_list()`

2. then for for each value in remaining column I multiply it by value from list and added as a new column

```
for val in list_of_values:
    df3['val_{}'.format(val)] = df3['% Total'] * val
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `np.outer` and DataFrame constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.outer(df["Total"], df["low_value"]),
    index=[df["Name"], df["Total"]],
    columns=df["low_value"],
).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
low_value Name     Total  33.783784  7.751938  1.057194  0.922509  0.198094
0           aa  0.000296   0.010000  0.002295  0.000313  0.000273  0.000059
1           bb  0.001290   0.043581  0.010000  0.001364  0.001190  0.000256
2           cc  0.009459   0.319561  0.073326  0.010000  0.008726  0.001874
3           dd  0.010840   0.366216  0.084031  0.011460  0.010000  0.002147
4           ee  0.050481   1.705439  0.391326  0.053368  0.046569  0.010000
```

Input DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'],
                  'Total':[.000296, .001290,.009459,.010840,.050481],
                  'low_value':[33.783784, 7.751938, 1.057194, .922509, .198094]})
```